# calculates the average of identical columns of several dataframes

Tags: list, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a function that calculates the average of identical columns of different dataframes stored in a list:

```
def mean(dfs):

     # declare an empty dataframe
     df_mean = pd.DataFrame()
     # assign the first column from each raw data framework to df
     for i in range(len(dfs)): 
          dfs[i].set_index(['Time'], inplace=True)

    for j in dfs[0].columns:
         for i in range(len(dfs)):
             df_mean[j] = pd.concat([df_mean,dfs[i][j]], axis=1).mean(axis=1)
    return df_mean

dfs = []
l1 = [[1,6,2,6,7],[2,3,2,6,8],[3,3,2,8,8],[4,5,2,6,8],[5,3,9,6,8]]
l2 = [[1,7,2,5,7],[2,3,0,6,8],[3,3,3,6,8],[4,3,7,6,8],[5,3,0,6,8]]

dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(l1, columns=['Time','25','50','75','100']))
dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(l2, columns=['Time','25','50','75','100']))

mean(dfs)
```

However, I got out only the mean of the first column right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat` on `Time` indexed list of dataframes, and `groupby` larger dataframe on `Time` and take `mean`

```
In [275]: pd.concat([d.set_index('Time') for d in dfs]).groupby(level='Time').mean()
Out[275]:
       25   50   75  100
Time
1     6.5  2.0  5.5  7.0
2     3.0  1.0  6.0  8.0
3     3.0  2.5  7.0  8.0
4     4.0  4.5  6.0  8.0
5     3.0  4.5  6.0  8.0
```

Or, since `Time` column is anyway common for both, atleast in this usecase

```
In [289]: pd.concat(dfs).groupby(level=0).mean()
Out[289]:
   Time   25   50   75  100
0   1.0  6.5  2.0  5.5  7.0
1   2.0  3.0  1.0  6.0  8.0
2   3.0  3.0  2.5  7.0  8.0
3   4.0  4.0  4.5  6.0  8.0
4   5.0  3.0  4.5  6.0  8.0
```

Details

```
In [276]: dfs
Out[276]:
[   Time  25  50  75  100
 0     1   6   2   6    7
 1     2   3   2   6    8
 2     3   3   2   8    8
 3     4   5   2   6    8
 4     5   3   9   6    8,    Time  25  50  75  100
 0     1   7   2   5    7
 1     2   3   0   6    8
 2     3   3   3   6    8
 3     4   3   7   6    8
 4     5   3   0   6    8]

In [277]: pd.concat([d.set_index('Time') for d in dfs])
Out[277]:
      25  50  75  100
Time
1      6   2   6    7
2      3   2   6    8
3      3   2   8    8
4      5   2   6    8
5      3   9   6    8
1      7   2   5    7
2      3   0   6    8
3      3   3   6    8
4      3   7   6    8
5      3   0   6    8
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Use python's `sum`, which well default to reducing the list based on the individual object's `__add__` method.  Then just divide by the length of the list.

```
sum(dfs) / len(dfs)

   Time   25   50   75  100
0   1.0  6.5  2.0  5.5  7.0
1   2.0  3.0  1.0  6.0  8.0
2   3.0  3.0  2.5  7.0  8.0
3   4.0  4.0  4.5  6.0  8.0
4   5.0  3.0  4.5  6.0  8.0
```

---

**Option 2**
Reconstruct while using `numpy`'s `mean` function

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.mean([d.values for d in dfs], 0),
    dfs[0].index, dfs[0].columns)

   Time   25   50   75  100
0   1.0  6.5  2.0  5.5  7.0
1   2.0  3.0  1.0  6.0  8.0
2   3.0  3.0  2.5  7.0  8.0
3   4.0  4.0  4.5  6.0  8.0
4   5.0  3.0  4.5  6.0  8.0
```

Comment: Aha, brilliant Sean!

Comment: Option 1 is __beautiful__ !

Comment: Thanks, piRSquared, you make it simple!